# Ajax event on Primefaces panel grid

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, breadcrumbs, panelgrid

I have a form in my page which has a panel grid inside of it, to show different info. One of the first rows is a breadcrum that shows a tail of selected items at a current moment. I want to define an ajax event for selecting an item and updating that breadcrum (and other components of my page as well). The problem is that I get a "Unable to attach  to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent" error. I searched that this is because PanelGrid Columns (which is the parent component of that breadcrum) doesn't support ajax events, the suggestion was to implement a Data Table, the problem is that  i have lots of different components such as Menus, SelectOneMenu, Command Buttons, Graphic Images, etc. that wont render in a DataTable. Is there a way to do this? Here's part of my code as a sample...

```
<h:form id="catPage">
            <p:panelGrid style="width: 100%; margin:auto; text-align: center;">
                <!-- Breadcrum of current caregory -->
                <p:row>  
                    <p:column colspan="4">  
                        <p:breadCrumb id="breadcrumcat" model="#{categoryBean.dislpayBreadCrumb()}">
                            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{categoryBean.selectCatListener}" update="breadcrumcat" />
                        </p:breadCrumb>
                    </p:column>  
                </p:row>
                <!-- More code... -->
          </p:panelGrid>
 </h:form>
```

Comment: Can you post both `categoryBean.dislpayBreadCrumb()` and `categoryBean.selectCatListener` ?

Comment: The breadcrumb itself does not support ajax; only the nested `<p:menu/>` is ajax-capable. In your case, you might have to hook into one of the component lifecycle states with `<f:event/>`, maybe the postAddToView event